# Reproducing population structure from 1000 Genomes Data

Tags: human-genome, phylogenetics, figure-reproduction

I recently tried to reproduce population structure with 1000 Genomes Project data (Phase 3, 2504 people).

According to supplementary material,

> To reduce the dataset, we used VCFtools to only keep biallelic, non-singleton SNV sites that were a minimum of 2 KB apart from each other. 
>   These variants were then merged and converted into PLINK format, giving us 1,286,213 throughout all the autosomes. 
>   PLINK was then used to filter the variants further, keeping only variants with a minor allele frequency of at least 0.05, 
>   and to convert the variants into binary PED format. After this filter 193,634 sites remained with data from 2,504 individuals in 26 populations.

And from [ftp repository](ftp://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/release/20130502/supporting/admixture_files/), I found the exact command-line to do it.

1. To get biallelic, non-singleton SNVs, all minimum of 2KB apart from each other

> ```
> ./vcftools --gzvcf
> ALL.chr1.phase3_shapeit2_mvncall_integrated_v4.20130502.genotypes.vcf.gz
> --thin 2000 --min-alleles 2 --max-alleles 2 --non-ref-ac 2 --plink --chr 1 --out ALL.chr1.phase3_shapeit2_filtered.20141217
> ```

2. To get variants with minor allele frequency of at least 0.05

> ```
> ./plink --file ALL.wgs.phase3_shapeit2_filtered.20141217.ped --out
> ALL.wgs.phase3_shapeit2_filtered.20141217.maf0.05 --make-bed --maf 0.05
> ```

3. To get population structure with ADMIXTURE program (v1.23)

> `./admixture ALL.wgs.phase3_shapeit2_filtered.20141217.maf0.05.bed K`

So I applied the same command (although versions of programs were not exactly the same) to the phase 3 data, and got different results (top: from supplementary data, bottom: my reproduction)
[image]

I basically did the same thing as in the supplementary document:

1. (for each chromosome \$ch) `bcftools view -v snps -O v $gzvcf | vcftools --vcf - --thin 2000 --min-alleles 2 --max-alleles 2 --non-ref-ac 2 --plink --chr ${ch} --out 1KGP_v5a_20130502.chr${ch}` [bcftools-1.9, vcftools 0.1.15]
2. (for each chromosome \$ch) `$plink --file 1KGP_v5a_20130502.chr${ch} --maf 0.05 --make-bed --out 1KGP_v5a_20130502.chr${ch}.maf0.05` [plink 1.9b]
3. (merge)
4. `admixture 1KGP_v5a_20130502.ALL.maf0.05.bed 5` [ADMIXTURE 1.3]

I would like to know if there's some step I've missed on the process. Otherwise, I cannot understand why the population structure look so different.

Comment: Welcome to the site. As you mention that you use different software version: What versions are you using? Could you try the same version to see if you are able to reproduce the same figure?

Comment: Did you perform your steps on all the chromosome or just chromosome 1?  Also in step 1 why did you skip the bedtools command that was used in the original paper?

Comment: @Llopis : I've noted the software versions I used at the end of command lines. When started with the same .bed/.bim files from the [repository] (ftp://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/release/20130502/supporting/admixture_files/), I was able to get the same output with ADMIXTURE 1.3 as with ADMIXTURE 1.23 (original paper). So, at least, ADMIXTURE version doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: @Bioathlete : I did for all autosomes. I followed the steps in the [file] (ftp://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/release/20130502/supporting/admixture_files/README.admixture_20141217) & supplementary section 9.7. I thought those steps can be directly applied to the released VCFs. Can you point me the bedtools command you mentioned?

Comment: sorry I meant bcftools not bedtools.  `bcftools view -v snps -O v $gzvcf `

Comment: @Bioathlete : The commands at the bottom were mine. Those at the top of the figure are from the supplementary document. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Ok then the question is reversed but still valid.  1) Why did you use bcftools? 2) Is the image from the paper using the whole genome or just chromosome 1?

Comment: @Bioathlete : 1) I used bcftools to select SNPs only, because it is described as they used SNVs. But the 1000G phase 3 VCF contained indels & SVs. 2) Image in the paper was also whole genome. After all, paper used 193,634 sites (over whole autosome) as input to ADMIXTURE, while I used 199,657 sites.

Comment: Did you check how many iterations they ran ADMIXTURE for, and how many you did? It may have yet to converge.